# Finding the "difference" between two string texts (Lua example)

Tags: string, algorithm, lua, difference, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to find the difference in text between two string values in Lua, and I'm just not quite sure how to do this effectively. I'm not very experienced in working with string patterns, and I'm sure that's my downfall on this one. Here's an example:

```
-- Original text
local text1 = "hello there"
-- Changed text
local text2 = "hello.there"

-- Finding the alteration of original text with some "pattern"
print(text2:match("pattern"))
```

In the example above, I'd want to output the text ".", since that's the difference between the two texts. Same goes for cases where the difference could be sensitive to a string pattern, like this:

```
local text1 = "hello there"
local text2 = "hello()there"

print(text2:match("pattern"))
```

In this example, I'd want to print "(" since at that point the new string is no longer consistent with the old one.

If anyone has any insight on this, I'd really appreciate it. Sorry I couldn't give more to work with code-wise, I'm just not sure where to begin.

Comment: what should the difference be for "hello there" and "hello htere"

Comment: Ideally, just the "h" in "htere". I'm just trying to find exactly where in the altered text, that it's no longer consistent, and just cut it off at that point and return the difference. That second example was a little misleading, I actually meant to say that it should return "(", instead of "()". I'll fix that.

Comment: then you will be able to do a for loop to iterate thru all the characters in string one and compare with string two. once you find a mismatch then stop

Comment: Oh, okay. I was thinking there'd be a shorter solution with string patterns, but perhaps I overlooked that. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the strings and find when they don't match.

```
function StringDifference(str1,str2)
    for i = 1,#str1 do --Loop over strings
        if str1:sub(i,i) ~= str2:sub(i,i) then --If that character is not equal to it's counterpart
            return i --Return that index
        end
    end
    return #str1+1 --Return the index after where the shorter one ends as fallback.
end

print(StringDifference("hello there", "hello.there"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for the longest length of a text. I was looking for the *difference* between the two. i.e the difference between "hello" and "hello." would be "."

Comment: @user7385467 However, having the index you can do `s:sub(i,i)` to get the character at that index.  Since two strings are involved, which character would you want, the 1st string's or the 2nd's?  It's trivial to change this function to give you the result you need.

Comment: @user7385567 I'm not returning the longest text, I'm returning the index in which the strings are different. For example if I returned "." How would you know where in the string it was? Right, you can't, so instead of giving you the character I tell you where it is. Also in the case str1 is shorter than str2 I return #str1+1 since str2 would continue for it would be nill for str1. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
local function get_inserted_text(old, new)
   local prv = {}
   for o = 0, #old do
      prv[o] = ""
   end
   for n = 1, #new do
      local nxt = {[0] = new:sub(1, n)}
      local nn = new:sub(n, n)
      for o = 1, #old do
         local result
         if nn == old:sub(o, o) then
            result = prv[o-1]
         else
            result = prv[o]..nn
            if #nxt[o-1] <= #result then
               result = nxt[o-1]
            end
         end
         nxt[o] = result
      end
      prv = nxt
   end
   return prv[#old]
end
```

Usage:

```
print(get_inserted_text("hello there", "hello.there"))    -->  .
print(get_inserted_text("hello there", "hello()there"))   -->  ()
print(get_inserted_text("hello there", "hello htere"))    -->  h
print(get_inserted_text("hello there", "heLlloU theAre")) -->  LUA
```